# Docker: Remove and create folder before doing cp

Tags: docker

Is it possible to create a folder if it is not existing before copy it?

```
docker cp /opt/project/build/core/bundle target_container:/opt/project/build/core
```

Normally there is only `/opt/project/build/` existing.

What I want to do is to copy the folder `bundle` and replace the existing folder and its files if it is existing. If it is not existing the folder `core/bundle` should be created and the files should be copied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`docker exec`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) will let you run commands in the container.

```
docker exec $target_container mkdir -p /opt/project/build/core
docker cp /opt/project/build/core/bundle $target_container:/opt/project/build/core/
```

*Note* the trailing `/` on the `cp` which tells docker to copy the source into the `core/` directory rather than naming `bundle` -> `core`

**Replace**

If want to completely "replace" an existing `bundle` directory rather than add files to it with the `cp`, then you would need start with removal.

```
docker exec $target_container sh -c \
  'rm -f /opt/project/build/core && mkdir -p /opt/project/build/core'
```

Comment: How can I remove the build folder and create new empty bundle folder? `docker exec $target_container rm -f /opt/project/build && docker exec $target_container mkdir -p /opt/project/build/core` Can I merge this to one command?

Comment: That would need to run via a script or shell like `sh`. I've updated the example

Answer (score 2):

A oneliner albeit less intuitive alternative:

```
tar xf - <dir> | docker exec -i <container> tar xf -
```

Comment: Nice.  `tar xf - build/core | docker exec -i <container> tar -C /opt/project -xf -` would allow different source and destination paths.

Comment: I'm not sure you can fit the `rm` in there though.

Comment: I think you can use `--recursive-unlink`